# Macros take too much memory

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel workbook with a bunch of macros in it. The Workbook has 4 worksheets, and each worksheet has different code implemented due to different restrictions based on each sheet has. Henceforth, when you close the workbook the size of it is around 80 MB. This is a problem as I cannot send the workbook via email due to its size.

Is there any possibility to disable the macros so the size of the workbook to be reduce? What I mean is that I want the macros to still be in the workbook, but not to affect the size of it as they are not activate it. Only when I enable the macros, then the size to turn again to its 80 MB size.

Maybe a button can be created that can disable the macros from the 4 worksheets and enable them when you press again? I am not sure how this can be approached or if there is a way to approach it, but any help would be must appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The size of a macro is really only the size of its textual source code, do you really have 80mb of VBA code?  What actually constitutes the 80mb?

Comment: Wow. I would rather suspect company logos or other embedded images to be the problem here.

Comment: I have a project with over 40 different modules, and I am not even close to touching 80MB. Try creating a fresh workbook and move the macros to that. Once you do, save it, and check the size again. If that one is 80MB it sounds like something is corrupted. Otherwise, it is far more likely that you have formatting issues, embedded images or information, a very large usedrange with formatting on the entire range, corruption of the workbook, or some combination of these.

Comment: I don't have any images. The problem might be because of the formatting issues as I do have large usedrange with formatting on entire range. I copied only the code to another workbook and yes, the size was insignificant, very low. I guess the file was corrupted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned above, it is not the VBA code, but most likely corruption or images causing the data increase. Here are some steps you can take to find the worksheet that is causing the problem:

1. Change the file extension from .xlsm to .zip
2. Open the file and you will see a directory structure
3. Open the xl directory, then the worksheets directory
4. Now you will see all the worksheets listed as .xml files along with their 
   size
5. When you find the culprit, exit out of the file, change the file extension back to .xlam
6. Go back into the file and look for the problem.  If unable to determine, you can copy/paste to another sheet or delete that sheet and recreate.

Comment: It may be an `.xlsm` file. `.xlam` files are for add-ins.